# '>=' not supported in piecewise operation 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

[image: df_1]
[image: df_2]

I am trying to get the 'camp' from df_1 in df_2 if the df_2.date>=df_1.startDate and df_2.date

I have tried piecewise operation:

```py
condition = [(df_2.date.values >= start_date)&(df_2.date.values <= end_date) for start_date, end_date in zip(df_1.startDate.values, df_1.endDate.values)]
```

```py
df_2['ID_matched'] = np.piecewise(np.zeros(len(sales)), condition, df_1.camp.values)
```

I am getting this error:

> '>=' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'

Is there any other way to solve this. 
Final output should contain these columns:
***sale,date,camp***

Comment: Looks like `start_date` is a string.  Hard to do a `>=` on that.  `values` is a numpy array, though it too might an array of strings.

Comment: Could you post sample format for ```start_date``` and ```end_date```

Comment: all the dates are in datetime64

Comment: I've posted the answer below with the steps performed

Answer (score 0):

I could get an answer to this solution.

**1. Created a list with unique camp names from df_1 and converted it to a dictionary with camp as key and numbers as elements.**

unique_campaign = list(set(df_1['camp']))
dictionary = dict(zip(df_1, list(range(1,len(unique_campaign)+1))))

**2. Using applymap converted the camp name to numbers from dictionary.**

df_1= df_1.applymap(lambda x: dictionary.get(x) if x in dictionary else x)

**3. np.piecewise operation**

start_end_date = zip(df_1.startDate.values, df_1.endDate.values)

conditions = [(df_2.date.values >= start_date) &
              (df_2.date.values <= end_date) for start_date, end_date in start_end_date ]

df_2['camp'] = np.piecewise(np.zeros(len(df_2)),                                conditions,df_1.camp.values).astype(int)

**4. By step 3 we have got the answer as an int. Now we map the integer from the dictionary to get the camp name.**

inv_dictionary = {values: keys for keys, values in dictionary.items()}

df_2['camp'] = df_2['camp'].apply(lambda x: inv_dictionary.get(x) if x in inv_dictionary else x)